# api for direct login

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, box-api

I am developing a java app for admin users in an organization.
The admin user has access to the organization main box folder.
I want my application to sign in the admin directly (without having to type his username and password in your box login site)

I read somewhere that you have a V1 authentication API that enables to do direct logins. Where can I find documentation regarding the direct login rest url?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported direct login method currently, unfortunately, so you'll have to stick to the [regular authentication system](http://developers.box.com/get-started/).

Comment: is it on the roadmap (via user/pass or user-generated tokens)?